# Questão sobre fila em C

Tags: c, array, estrutura-de-dados, stack, fila

Alguém pode analisar esse meu código e ver o que pode estar errado?. É um exercício de simulação que recebi para fazer na faculdade. 
Erro: O código executa, porém entra em looping. Qual while tem problema?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10

int suc(int p){
  int temp;
  if (p==N)
        temp=1;
  else
        temp=p+1;
  return(temp);
}

void inserir(char F[], int i, int *f, int *over, int *c, char ch){
    *over= 0;
    if(suc(*f)==i){
        printf("Overflow na fila\n");
        *over=1;
    }
    else{
        *f=suc(*f);
        F[*f]=ch;
        *c++;
      }
}

char remover(char F[], int *i, int f, int *c){
    char temp;
    if(*i==f)
        printf("Underflow na fila");
    else
    {   *i=suc(*i);
        temp=F[*i];
        *c++;
    }
    return(temp);
}

void exibirSomenteFila(char F[], int i, int f){
  int x;
  if (i == f)
    printf ("\nFila vazia");
  else
   { x=i;
     while (x != f)
       { x = suc(x);
         printf(" %c ",F[x]);
       }
   }
   printf ("\n");
}

void main()
{
char F[N+1], ch;
int i,f, minutos, contador, ov, r, k ;

minutos=0;
i=1;
f=1;
contador=0;
ov=0;

while(contador<40){

    minutos++;

    if (minutos % 2==0){
        inserir(F, i, &f, &ov, &contador, 'a');
        if (ov==1){
            printf("A area sera esvaziada");
            exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
            while (i != f){
                ch=remover(F, &i, f, &c);
                printf("%d", ch);
            }
            inserir(F, i, &f, &ov, &contador, 'a');
            exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
        }
    }

    if (minutos%3==0){
        r=rand() % 3;
        k=1;
        while (k<=r){
            ch=remover(F, &i, f, &contador);
            printf("%c", ch);
            k++;
        }
    }

    if (minutos%8==0)
        exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
}
exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);

}
```

Comment: você poderia ao menos dizer alguma coisa sobre o erro que ocorre ? ou será que isso é segredo ?  _"I'm a doctor Jim, not a psychic"_

Comment: José, acho que é um erro na retirada do valor no fim da fila.

Comment: `Line 74: [Error] 'c' was not declared in this scope.` Você está passando uma variável 'c' que não existe como parâmetro da função. Declare a variável c e coloque um valor nela antes de usá-la.

Comment: O certo era eu usar contador e não c, já arrumei isso. Porém entra em looping.

Comment: @YgorFraga Coloque as informações solicitadas na própria pergunta, usando o botão [edit].

Answer (score 0):

O seu contador não está sendo atualizado. Se colocar um `printf("\n Contador = %d", contador)` dentro do `while` do `main` vai ver isso.

Fiz duas alterações no seu código:

1. Usei `int main()`, você usa `void main()`
2. Usei `*c = *c + 1`, no lugar de todos os `*c++`

Ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10

int suc(int p){

    int temp;
    if (p==N)
        temp=1;
    else
        temp=p+1;
    return(temp);
}

void inserir(char F[], int i, int *f, int *over, int *c, char ch){

    *over= 0;
    if(suc(*f)==i){
        printf("Overflow na fila\n");
        *over=1;
    }
    else{
        *f=suc(*f);
        F[*f]=ch;
        *c = *c + 1;
    }

}

char remover(char F[], int *i, int f, int *c){

    char temp;
    if(*i==f)
        printf("Underflow na fila");
    else
    {   *i=suc(*i);
        temp=F[*i];
        *c = *c + 1;
    }

    return(temp);
}

void exibirSomenteFila(char F[], int i, int f){

   int x;
   if (i == f)
     printf ("\nFila vazia");
   else
   { 
       x=i;
       while (x != f){ 
        x = suc(x);
        printf(" %c ",F[x]);
       }
   }
   printf ("\n");
}

int main(){

    char F[N+1], ch;
    int i,f, minutos, contador, ov, r, k ;

    minutos=0;
    i=1;
    f=1;
    contador=0;
    ov=0;

    while(contador<40){

        minutos++;
        if (minutos % 2==0){
            inserir(F, i, &f, &ov, &contador, 'a');
            if (ov==1){
                printf("A area sera esvaziada");
                exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
                while (i != f){
                    ch=remover(F, &i, f, &contador);
                    printf("%d", ch);
                }
                inserir(F, i, &f, &ov, &contador, 'a');
                exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
            }
        }

        if (minutos%3==0){
            r=rand() % 3;
            k=1;
            while (k<=r){
                ch=remover(F, &i, f, &contador);
                printf("%c", ch);
                k++;
            }
        }

        if (minutos%8==0)
            exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);
    }

    exibirSomenteFila(F,i,f);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MXZaiv).

Uma dica, tome cuidado com a tabulação do código.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. Mas por que não estava contando com *c++? e nesse código faria diferença usar o void main()?

Comment: @YgorFraga , sinceramente eu não sei por que *c++, não funcionou. Você pode fazer outra pergunta e outros usuários vão saber te responder isso. Eu sempre uso *x = *x +1. Já sobre o void main(), funções do tipo "void" não retornam nenhum valor, isso quer dizer que elas são apenas procedimentos, são estáticos. O correto é utilizar a função "main" como inteira, pois o seu valor poderá indicar se o programa foi finalizado corretamente ou não.